# Salesforce Frontdoor.jsp returns status 200 instead of 302 when behind firewall/VPN

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, authentication, session, frontdoor.jsp

The Salesforce CLI opens DX Scratch Orgs, Sandboxes, and Production environments by executing the `force:org:open` command.  If you add the `--urlonly` flag to that command, it reveals the URL that is based to the operating system's web browser.  That URL is the of the following format:

```
https://force-dream-3745-dev-ed.cs23.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00D35000000HaHH!ASAAQGaIo0ZvNUPEnLAkdDvFxFuWHjW1tWUmkQE6dkSm3T0erMqXBuys8PN.Lf47t_GTVZZUi.SOUQS2UXXcpalpiPTm14qe
```

This URL [uses Frontdoor.jsp to Bridge an Existing Session Into Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_frontdoorjsp.htm&type=5).

If things operate normally, you can copy and paste that URL into a web browser and it will authenticate you to that org and bring you to the main home page.  If you open the web browser's developer tools console and look at the Network tab, you will see a progression of calls between your browser and Salesforce.  The call to "frontdoor.jsp" should return a status code 302 redirect to "contentDoor?startUrl=..." page and the org opens from there.  In checking the "frontdoor.jsp" response headers, I see the setting of multiple cookies including the `sid` cookie.

In my case, this is not occurring when I try to access certain scratch orgs from behind a corporate firewall.  The issue is that the call to "frontdoor.jsp" returns a status code of 200. Because of this, there is no setting of session cookies and I simply end up on the main login page for an org.

When I get off the VPN/out from behind the firewall, and I try to access the scratch org using the "frontdoor.jsp", it returns the correct/expected status 302 response and I am able to get into the org.

My question is does anyone know under what condition would the "frontdoor.jsp" return a simple 200 instead of the proper 302 status code?  Is it a connected app security policy issue?  Clearly the fact that I am behind a VPN/firewall is part of the issue, but what specifically in the org's security policies would be having issues with that fact?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers!